# Flex MXMLC Ant task steals the window focus

Tags: flash, mxmlc

Has anyone noticed the following behavior building Flex programs using the mxmlc ANT task (running in the background): as the MXMLC task starts, it steals the window focus from whatever application is currently running, and then gives it back again! This is extremely disruptive.

Is there a way to run the MXMLC task "headless" so it doesn't interact at all with the window system?

I'm running on Mac OS X (10.5.8, if that matters), and Flash 4.0.1 (although the behavior existed on 3.x as well).

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Note the -compiler.headless-server option (http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/)

I just tried setting this to true in an mxmlc ant task of mine and it prevented the stealing of focus. HTH.